# Should i enable zram and/or lower swappiness value?

Tags: 12.04, swap, download-speed, zram

I use ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have 2GB RAM. Now, that is split about 55-45 memory-swap. My CPU is almost flatlined!
Could I get faster leaner meaner more efficient performance if I lowered swappiness down to 10 and/or enabled ZRAM. Or should I leave well-enough alone? I am under the impression that zram is built into Ubuntu 12.04 and only needs to be enabled with a simple command. Should I do both together or should I do one but not the other?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you should enable zram, but not in 12.04 as I still didn't test it. I'm testing zram with K/ubuntu 14.04 in a hp compaq 6710b with 1.5gb of ram and I have noticed a big improvement in the overall office work performance. 
Before the swap to disk started to happen with few apps open, and it push down the performance. Now I open lot of apps with big memory in use and the computer work very well with zram activated.

In 14.04 LTS you just need to do it: 
sudo apt-get install zram-config 
and reboot after install

That's it. 
Important notice: it's recommended only for desktop/tablet/laptop/phone. Not for server, as there is completely different scenario.